# Fixed element not working in Mobile views

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-position

**Fixed menu is not working in mobile or responsive**

I have a floating menu on the website site, it is working perfectly on desktop sized window, but when i resize the window to mobile size, the menu isn't floating anymore, and only became part of the page. I am almost certain that it has something to do with my other elements that are fixed or relative in position, but couldn't find the culprit.

It is the blue menu on the right side.

The floating menu is made with a plugin called "sticky side buttons", I have reached out for help but no response yet, so I thought I would try asking here.

URL: http://umassfd.org

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
#newBridge .nb-icon-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 77px;
    min-width: 146px;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, but it doesn't seem to be working. Where did you get those element class and ID from? I can't seem to find those. I tried to apply the code to the class I can find but no luck.